# Reading individual bz2 files from a tar file

Tags: python, tar

I'm trying to read many bz2 files within a tar file, a file has the following structure:

```
2013-01.tar
  01\01\00\X.json.bz2\X.json
  01\01\02\X.json.bz2\X.json
```

I'm able to get the filenames as follows:

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open(filepath, 'r')
tar_members_names = [filename for filename in tar.getnames()]
# Side question: How would I only return files and no directories?
```

Which returns a list of the .bz2 files. Now I'm trying to extract them (temporarily) using:

```
inner_filename = tar_members_names[0]
t_extract = tar.extractfile(inner_filename)
```

The following code to extract the json file returns an error, however. How would I go about retrieving the JSON files line by line?

```
import bz2
txt = bz2.BZ2File(t_extract)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, ExFileObject found
txt = bz2.decompress(t_extract)
TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not ExFileObject
```

I've been unable to figure out how to return a buffer from the tar file instead of the current ExFileObject (how to convert it to a buffer?), any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: like the error says, you're passing an ExFileObject, not a string or TarInfo object like "extractfile" expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BZ2File` expects a file *name* as first argument and you pass a file *object* (i.e. an object which has the same API as what Python returns for `open()`).

To do what you want, you'll have to read all the bytes from `t_extract` yourself and call `bz2.decompress(data)` or use `BZ2Decompressor` to stream the data through it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it clears up what is going wrong. Could you provide a hint as to where I could find how to do this? Would I first have to save the extracted file to disk and read it from there?

Comment: That depends a bit on the file size. If it's small, you can read all of it into a buffer (`data = t_extract.read()`) and decompress with one call to `bz2.decompress(data)`. Otherwise, you have to use a temporary file and stream the data through `BZ2Decompressor`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. They're reasonably small, so the buffer should work.

Comment: I had one last question. When reading data = t_extract.read(), what kind of object am I retrieving? Printing type(t_extract.read()) actually prints the entire contents of the file (a buffer?). I've been able to iterate over it utilizing txt = bz2.decompress(data) & 'for line in txt.split('\n')', but it seems like a hack more than how I should do it. Any thoughts?

Comment: `read()` returns the file's content. The built-in Python 2.x methods will return a `str` object. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects
Python 3 is more complex: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object